# MVC3 modify MembershipCreateuser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

As I chose to extend the membership provider by creating a new table to record additional user information, at registration I need to populate this new table with the uniqueUserId from the membership table. please pardon my ignorance I am a novice. How do I modify this code to add the unique key to say a table called UsrProfile

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

                    //add unique user id to myprofile

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the database technology you are using.  Since you don't mention it, all we'd be doing is guessing what technology you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique Key from default Membership Provider can be retrieved by :

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

so you can easily create relation between user and your other tables. 
But if you want to store additional properties of users why not utilize something that's already there like Profiles ? You only need to add the below structure to web.config

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="EverLoggedOn" defaultValue="False" type="System.Boolean" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

more info about profiles : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Comment: Thanks torm  in my initial research i bumped into a lot of criticisms alleging that  the default profileprovider  was not scalable hence I decided to avoid it

Comment: typically I will have there different kinds of users and they will all have to provide in addition to some basic profile info like Fname,Mname,Lname,DOB,Citizenship,Residence,Mobile,Phone,Occupation,MembtypeID and others based on membertypID What I intended to do on first login I populate myprofile table with the persons unique Id and before a person makes his or her first posting on the site the person will be  redirected complete the extra profile data. I am however ready to go by default profileprovider if you think I would not get caught in management bottlenecks in the future

Comment: thanks @torm I finally have used this solution to achieve what I wanted